# Reading a file of larger size from server with spring rest api from the performance point of view

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-rest, rest

I able to read the log file from the server and able to download the same successfully through spring rest API, now my query os that right now my input file size at the server is of 500 MB but anyhow if my file reaches to 1 GB, so in that case what modifications I need to do in the below piece of code to improve the performance

```
  @GetMapping("/download/{filename}")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(@RequestParam String filename) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(SERVER_LOCATION + File.separator + filename + EXTENSION);

        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + filename + EXTENSION);
        header.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        header.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        header.add("Expires", "0");

        Path path = get(file.getAbsolutePath());
        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path));

        final ResponseEntity<Resource> resourceResponseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(header)
                .contentLength(file.length())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                .body(resource);
        return resourceResponseEntity;
    }
```

Comment: You are reading it in memory and them streaming it. Don't. Read the file and directly stream, don't first read it as a byte-array. Use a `InputStreamResource` or `FileReousrce` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is reading the whole file into memory by using `Files.readAllBytes(path)`. While this might work for smallish files, it will break with large files or a lot of open files. What you should do instead is not read it but use, for instance, the `File` or an `InputStream`.

```
File file = new File(SERVER_LOCATION + File.separator + filename + EXTENSION);
Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(file);
```

or

```
Path path = get(file.getAbsolutePath());
Resource resource = new InputStreamResource(Files.newInputStream(path));
```

This will load only when needed and directly stream the result.